# Запятые между неоднородными определениями

Tags: пунктуация

Мне кажется, что здесь нужны запятые, но две или одна? И по какому правилу? Все определения неоднородные, но одно из них распространенное и не заканчивает собой этого ряда определений. Можно ли это рассматривать как уточнение?

Мелкие взаимопроникающие (,) подобные профилю упорной резьбы (,) концентричные конуса...

У Лопатина нашла, что определения могут быть уточняющими: Катер шел, всё время подвигаясь в черной, почти чернильного цвета, тени, отбрасываемой высокими прибрежными скалами.

Также нашла в интернете: У диких форм плоды мелкие, подобные крупноплодному шиповнику.

Можно ли сказать, что это как раз тот случай?

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется более естественным перечислить собственные определяющие признаки, а затем добавить сопоставляющее уточнение, тогда и с запятыми проще выйдет:

Мелкие взаимопроникающие концентричные конуса, подобные профилю упорной резьбы, ...

Comment: Да, ну а если не менять автора?

Comment: Тогда нужно знать по технике, "взаимопроникающие" связано с "подобием профилю" или это перечисление независимых признаков. Если это подобие связано с проникновением, то я бы поставил обе запятых (уточнение относится только к предшествующему признаку), а если нет, то только первую (оно относится в целом к определяемому существительному).

Answer (score 2):

Мелкие взаимопроникающие,подобные профилю упорной резьбы, концентричные конуса..

Обособленный определительный оборот   является уточняющим по отношению к прилагательному "взаимопроникающие" - оно уточняет способ "проникновения", или соединения (по типу резьбового соединения с упорной резьбой, профиль такой резьбы - неравнобокая трапеция).

Answer (score 1):

> Мелкие взаимопроникающие (,) подобные профилю упорной резьбы (,)
>   концентричные конуса...

Не смог пока понять, что из себя представляет эта конструкция с концентричными конусами. Потому ничего о знаках препинания сказать не могу.

Отмечу только, что форму мн. числа "конус**а**" словари не рекомендуют применять. К примеру, у Еськовой так:

> **конус**, -а, *мн.* -ы, -ов # *Технич. деталь*
>
> **!** *не рек. профессион. мн.* конус**а**, -**о**в

Answer (score 1):

Мелкие взаимопроникающие,подобные профилю упорной резьбы концентричные конуса..
У Розенталя помню правило, ксающееся однородных определений, если первое - одиночное, второе распространенное.Правда, в его примерах распространенное определение выражено причастным оборотом, но  такое правило вполне подходит для случаев, когда после одиночного определения (в данном предложении после слова "взаимопроникающие") следует распространенное, выраженное прилагательным с зависимыми словами. Согласитесь, что если был бы другой порядок слов, то знаки препинания были бы иными: Мелкие взаимопроникающие концентричные конуса,подобные профилю упорной резьбы

Comment: Абсолютно с вами согласен, Виктор.Само по себе "взаимопроникающие" не может служить определением к "подобные"